# How to add a route?

Tags: plugin-development, routing

I'm writing a wordpress plugin. I want to add a route to frontend, for example `mysite.com/myroute/` that runs a php file( located in `wp-content/plugin/myplugin/my_route_handler.php`).

I need to load layout and every wordpress specifics in this route.

Is this possible? How to do this?

Comment: Have you read about [tag:endpoints]?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin wp-mvc which provides you the Routing functionality as some other frameworks. Check this documentation: [**WP MVC Routing**](http://wpmvc.org/documentation/routing/)